# Solving $x(x+1)y' + y = x(x+1)^{2}e^{-x^2}$ in $(-1,0)$

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

What I tried to do:

I divided both sides by $x(x+1)$: $$y' + \frac{1}{x(x+1)}y = (x+1)e^{-x^2}$$

This has the form $$y'+P(x)y = Q(x)$$
The general solution would be (supposing $f(a)=b, a \in (-1,0)$ ): $$f(x) = be^{-A(x)} + e^{-A(x)} \cdot \int_{a}^{x} e^{A(x)}(x+1)e^{-x^2} dx$$

Where $A(x) = \int \frac{1}{x(x+1)} dx = \ln \left ( \frac {x}{x+1} \right ) + D$

And $ \int_{a}^{x} e^{A(x)}(x+1)e^{-x^2} dx = \frac{1}{2} (C-e^{-x^2})$

The problem is that I'm making my answer depend on two constants ($D$ and $C$), which should not happen since this is a first order equation.
The solution is simply:$$ f(x) = \frac{1}{2} \left (1+\frac{1}{x} \right ) \left (C-e^{-x^2} \right )$$

What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the whole equation is defined up to a constant anyway, you don't need the constant D as $e^{A(x)} \propto e^{ln\left(\frac{x}{1+x} \right)} = \left(\frac{x}{1+x} \right)$.

Also I don't know where you get the C from in a definite integral.

I got something like
$e^{ln\left(\frac{x}{1+x} \right)} = \left(\frac{x}{1+x} \right)$

$\implies \frac{x}{x+1} y' + \frac{1}{(1+x)^2}y = xe^{-x^2} $

$\implies \frac{d}{dx} \left(\frac{x}{1+x} y \right) =  xe^{-x^2}$

$\iff \frac{x}{1+x} y = \int xe^{-x^2} dx$

$\iff \frac{x}{1+x} y = -\frac{1}{2}e^{-x^2} + A$

$\iff y = -\frac{1+x}{2x}e^{-x^2} + \frac{A(1+x)}{x}$

$\implies y = \frac{1+x}{2x}(C - e^{-x^2})$ for some new constant $C = 2A$

in the way that you want it :)

Comment: $ F(x) = \int_{a}^{x} f(t)dt$ is actually a different way to write an indefinite integral, as a function of the upper bound... the constant $C$ is nothing more than the antiderivative calculated in $a$, such that different indefinite integrals will differ only by a constant... the definite integral $  \int_{a}^{b} f(t)dt$ is then $F(b) - F(a)$... I used this notation because I think it's easier to solve ODEs with initial conditions using it...

Comment: Apart from that, your solution was very nice. Thank you